# What is the vertical complement of side-by-side?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I searched on google and came up with `over-under` in an article about shotgun barrels comparison. Also, over-under image search yields mostly shotgun images. Is this the vertical equivalent of side-by-side? If not, what is?

[image: Colored Squares]

I mean as far as I know that Tosca and Beryl Green squares are side by side. What *are* Beryl Green and Albescent White squares?

Comment: washer-dryer combos can be described as "stacked" when one is above the other.

Comment: In design terms you might say they were _stacked vertically_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of design - especially website design in my experience - one would say "Beryl Green" and "Albescent White" were *stacked vertically*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see, http://www.cabelas.com/category/Over-Under-Side-by-Side-Shotguns/104802480.uts

Double-barreled handguns, notably Derringers are also produced in an over-under configuration.  Google "under-over Derringer" and choose "Images", and you'll see many examples.

Apart from firearms, you could use the word "adjacent".  Miriam-Webster's Thesaurus also suggests, "abutting, adjoining, bordering, conterminous, contiguous, flanking, flush, fringing, joining, juxtaposed, neighboring, skirting, touching, verging".   My own experience is that for the two colored boxes the more commonly-used words of those listed would be "adjacent", "abutting" and "adjoining", in that order.  Since so many disparate objects may be side-by-side, a generic use-frequency survey, like Google's, would not be very persuasive. For example, if you had presented a photo of two houses, the most common joint adjective would likely be "neighboring".

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to see an example that has nothing to do with guns if possible.

Comment: Fridge-freezers come over-under, under-over, and side by side. [Sub-Zero](http://www.subzero-wolf.com/sub-zero/full-size-refrigeration/builtin-refrigerators/30-inch-built-in-over-under-refrigerator-freezer)